# How to put 2 PDF files into a single page

Tags: pdfpages

I have two separate pdf files which, when combined, are smaller than A4 paper. Is there a way to create a single page out of them without page break with these two being rendered on the same page? I've tried to use `pdfpages`, but I only get them on separate pages.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: You can use `includegraphics` instead of `includepdf`.

Answer (score 6):

There are two possibilities.

1. Using the package `graphicx`:
   As long as you compile with `pdflatex` you can include every external pdf file with `\includegraphics`.

   ```
   \includegraphics{doc1.pdf}
   \includegraphics{doc2.pdf}
   ```
2. Using the package `pdfpages`: The package provides the command `\includepdfmerge` which can handle multiple pdf files:

   ```
   \includepdfmerge[nup=1x2, landscape]{doc1.pdf, doc2.pdf}
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This code will work fine

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{p{1\linewidth}}
        \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{1.pdf}
        \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{2.pdf}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```